# Google Sign in CocoaPods Install in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-signin

I am currently working on a Swift-based application that uses a mix of Objective-C and Swift-based Cocoapods.  
My `Podfile` looks something like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.6'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

My pods worked perfectly up until I added Google Signin.
When I did `pod install`, I got the following error:

```
[!] The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static
binaries: (~/Pods/GoogleAppUtilities/Libraries/libOpenInChrome.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleAuthUtilities/Libraries/libGTMOAuth2_internal.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleAuthUtilities/Libraries/libGTMOAuth2_external.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_full.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_core.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries/libGSDK_Overload.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_iPhone.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_core.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_UIFont+LineHeight.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_SystemVersion.a, 
~/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_StringEncoding.a, 
~/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_RoundedRectPath.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_Regex.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSStringXML.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSStringHTML.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSScannerJSON.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_KVO.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_GTMURLBuilder.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_DebugUtils.a, 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_AddressBook.a, and 
~/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTMStackTrace.a)
```

Also, as soon as I add Google Signin, all the modulemaps and umbrella headers for my other pods disappear, breaking all of them.

[This issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3194) from Cocoapods seems to reference this problem as being related to my use of !use_frameworks, but only suggests a workaround (`--use-libraries`) on the pod publishing end, not from a user standpoint.  Is this something I need to wait for Google to fix in their podspec, or is there something I can do on my end to get the Sign-in pod working?

If not, does Google still provide a way to manually install this SDK without Cocoapods?

Comment: Google Sign-in without cocoapods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783709/google-signin-without-cocoapods

Comment: Thank you! This will work in the meantime, but it'd be nice to get it up and running in Cocoapods.

Comment: @thelaws Any alternative to use Google Cloud Message?

Comment: @willrichman We did get it running with cocoapods initially, it just doesn't build with the use_frameworks flag (same error as you have).

Comment: @Ana Sorry, never heard of that. Doesn't seem related to this question?

Comment: @thelaws if you try to use Google/GoogleCloudMessaging gives the same error.

Comment: @Ana Yeah, it seems that any of Google's pods won't install if you're using the `!use_frameworks` flag, which is required if your project is in Swift and uses Obj-C pods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by adding this to my bridging header:

```
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>
```

then swift had access to google sign in :)

Comment: Be sure to configure the project to use the bridging header in `Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Objective-C Bridging Header `

Answer (score 1):

try below pod

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 2.2'
```

Comment: `[!] Unable to find a specification for `GoogleSignIn (~> 2.2)``

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite late answering this question, but it would appear that the `pod install` problem was a problem with Cocoapods itself. I updated Cocoapods to its most recent version (now 0.39.0), and I was able to install all the Google pods. I was then able to add lines to my bridging header as niebloomj suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32012825/4146745) and access all of the libraries in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when running 'pod lib lint' on another project.  I fixed it by including the --use-libraries and --allow-warnings command line directives.  Perhaps this might help you in resolving your issue.

```
pod lib lint --use-libraries --allow-warnings
```

Comment: From what I can tell, this is what Google should be doing on their end when they create the pod.  Is there a way I don't know about to add this on my end in either the Podfile or during `pod install`?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error not long ago. I just deleted

```
use_frameworks!
```

from the podfile and now is working fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this without breaking other Objective-C pods in my Swift project. It looks like this fix is in Google's court.