# Upgrading from Google Sign-In SDK 1.0.0 to 2.0.1 fails to compile on SKStore references

Tags: ios, google-signin

Following the directions to upgrade the Google Sign-In SDK from 1.0.0 to 2.0.1 on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/ causes the following compile error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDStoreKit.o)
  "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
      l003 in GoogleSignIn(GIDStoreKit.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `StoreKit.framework` to your Target's **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**.

Also double check that `AddressBook.framework` and `SystemConfiguration.framework` are also linked.