# error code when using GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID =

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, google-signin

I have an app which I used to use `Auth2` to sign in using a client Id and client secret  but now I have to use `Google Sign In`

I have followed the instructions as I understand them but when I build I get this error

> -[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d49a40

I have added the framework
I have imported the headers
I have made a separate `GoogleServices-info.plist` with
`CLIENT_ID` and  `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID`

I have put the following code in my ViewDidLoad

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.delegate = self;
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.uiDelegate = self;
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID = @"55240XXXXX13-aduv6ncti03giqt46s3oq4t83plqck10.apps.googleusercontent.com" ;
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.scopes=@[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"];
```

If I comment out the `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID` the app builds just fine but when I don't the app crashes with the above error.

I have linked the library `-ObjC` also.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to work this out.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I am really stumped on this. It compiles fine if I remove out the clientID line, and then complains when I click the Google login button that I didn't set the clientID. All the other discussions keep mentioning the -ObjC otherlinkerflag. I've added/removed/triple-checked that dumb flag so many times it's giving me a headache.

Comment: I figured it out. I wrote it up here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37442084/1359088. The answer below by f0go gave me a crucial piece to the puzzle with libz.tbd.

Answer (score 2):

You should import the following frameworks:

- AddressBook.framework
- SafariServices.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- libz.tbd

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions found on internet but couldn't solve this then I tried manual integration instead of pod and it worked for me.